# Winding Number of a product of curves in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, winding-number

I was reading a proof for a proposition about winding numbers under perturbation, and ultimately it came down to saying 
$$n(\beta,0)=n(\alpha,0)+n(\gamma,0)$$
where $\beta(t)=\alpha(t)\gamma(t)$, and $\alpha,\gamma,\beta: [a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ are curves in the complex plane.

Its `proof' of this was that "the argument of a product is the sum of the arguments."  Taking Ahlfors viewpoint that the winding number not be defined with regards to the argument, I wanted to prove this result more generally using the definition:
$$n(\gamma,w)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma{\frac{dz}{z-w}}$$
where $\gamma$ is a piecewise continuously-differentiable curve not containing $w$ in its image.

I first proved it for when $w=0$, which is quite easy.  See the end for this proof.

1. Does this result actually hold true in the general case where $w$ is arbitrary? That is:

> For $\alpha,\beta$ piecewise continuously differentiable closed curves $\alpha,\beta:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and $w$ not in the images of either $\alpha,\beta$, we define $\gamma:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by $\gamma(t)=\alpha(t)\beta(t)$.  Then
>   $$n(\gamma,w)=n(\alpha,w)+n(\beta,w).$$

1. Is there a way to reduce it to the case where $w=0$?

Proof for $w=0$:
Given $\alpha, \beta:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ with 0 not in their images and piecewise continuously-differentiable, I define a curve $\gamma$ defined by $\gamma(t)=\alpha(t)\beta(t)$ for $t\in [a,b]$.  Now, since this is product of piecewise continuously-differentiable closed, $\gamma$ is also piecewise continuously-differentiable closed, with derivative $\alpha'\beta+\alpha\beta'$.

Now, $n(\gamma,0)$ is defined since if there exists a $t\in [a,b]$ such that $\gamma(t)=0$, then $0=\alpha(t)\beta(t)$, and it follows that 0 is an element of the image of at least one of $\alpha,\beta$, contrary to assumption.

Next, we compute the following:
$$\int_\gamma{\frac{dz}{z}}=\int_a^b{\frac{\gamma'}{\gamma}dt}=\int_a^b{\frac{\alpha'\beta+\alpha\beta'}{\alpha\beta}dt}=\int_a^b{\frac{\alpha'}{\alpha}dt}+\int_a^b{\frac{\beta'}{\beta}dt}$$
from which it follows that
$$n(\gamma,0)=n(\alpha,0)+n(\beta,0)$$
by dividing by $2\pi i$.

Now, my hope was to reduce the general case when $w$ is arbitrary to the above case when $w=0$.  The 'obvious' approach is to translate everything by $-w$, moving $w$ to the origin and $\alpha(t),\beta(t)$ to $\alpha(t)-w,\beta(t)-w$.  However, this clearly does not preserve products, since then $(\alpha-w)(\beta-w)=\alpha\beta-w(\alpha+\beta)+w^2$, which is clearly not $\alpha\beta-w$.  Moreover, $(\alpha-w)(\beta-w)$ has derivative equal to $\alpha'\beta+\alpha\beta'-w(\alpha'+\beta')$, and at least it doesn't seem to me that it is true that
$$\int_a^b{\frac{\alpha'\beta+\alpha\beta'-w(\alpha'+beta')}{\alpha\beta-w(\alpha+\beta)+w^2}dt}=\int_a^b{\frac{\alpha'\beta +\alpha\beta'}{\alpha\beta-w}dt}$$

Comment: $\mathbb{C}^*$ is a topological group under multiplication. In this case the product you are working with coincides up to homotopy with the product by concatination if paths. The argument us in the beginning if Spanier. You can imitate that proof to get what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this result actually hold true in the general case where $w$ is arbitrary?

No. The fact that we use multiplication makes $0$ a special element of the space. For a counterexample, take $\alpha(t)=2e^{it}$, $\beta(t)=3e^{it}$ and $w=5$. Then $\gamma(t) = 6e^{2it}$, hence $n(\gamma, w)=2$. But $n(\alpha,w)=n(\beta,w)=0$.

Comment: That's certainly a simple counterexample.  Thanks!

Comment: For composition of curves there is a result: product theorem for Brouwer degree.   https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Brouwer_degree#Product_theorem.

Answer (score 1):

$n(ab,w)=n(a,w)+n(b,w)$ is not true but $n((a-w)(b-w),0)=n(a,w)+n(b,w)$ is true.

Proof: let $a'=(a-w)$ and $b'=(b-w) $

$n((a-w)(b-w),0)=n(a'b',0)=n(a',0)+n(b',0)=n(a,w)+n(b,w)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).